# Overloading the assignment operator or use the default one?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

If I have

```
Class A {
    int x;
};

Class B {
    vector<A> y;
    //...
};
```

And I want to overload the assignment operator `=` in B. Will using the default `=` operator be enough? Will it just use the `=` operator of `vector` on `y` member?

**EDIT:** say I wanted to implement something like that myself, so that b = k will work if both b and k are of type B. would I need to explicitly call the vector destructor to free the y member of b, inside the implementation?

How will it look like?

```
B& B::operator=(const B& b) {
    if (this == &b) {
       return *this;
    }
    y = b.y;
    return *this;
}
```

Will the original vector `this->y` destructed here? why?

Comment: Why do you want to overload it if you don't know the default will do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will using the default `=` operator be enough?

Yes, it's sufficient, unless you have any resources that need *special treatment* or parameters.

> Will it just use the `=` operator of vector on y member?

Yes, the generated default assignment operator/copy constructor will call any assignment operators/copy constructors available for member variables automatically.

---

> ```
>  B& B::operator=(const B& b) {
>      if (this == &b) {
>            return *this;
>        }
>        y = b.y;
>        return *this;
>  }
> ```
>
> Will the original vector this->y destructed here? why?

Yes, it will be *"destructed"*, since the `operator=()` definition of `vector<A>` implies to do so.

It's not really the destructor function is called, but the implementation of the assignment operator does imply the same behaviour as there would be a new instance constructed, and all of the contained member destructors will be called when the vector is cleared.

Comment: say I wanted to implement something like that myself, so that `b = k` will work if both `b` and `k` are of type `B`. would I need to explicitly call the `vector` destructor to free the `y` member of `b`, inside the implementation?

Comment: @Stabilo _"would I need to explicitly call the vector destructor to free the y member of b, inside the implementation?"_  No, you never call any destructor functions _explicitly_. These will be called automatically when the containing instance is destructed. Or did I misunderstand something from your explanations?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have special cases (like owning pointers, or `unique_ptr`), you can just not-define it and use the default one. In your case it should be fine.
In case of owning pointers, you would suddenly have two objects pointing to the same data in memory, which might not be the behaviour you want (same goes for `shared_ptr`.
`unique_ptr` can't be copied, so the default assignment operator won't work in this case and you'd have to write an overload.